# Plot shaded time period (geom_rect) inside dplyr do loop with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm having trouble getting a `geom_rect` to display a shaded area when using `facet_wrap` and the dplyr `do(...)` to generate the plots.

**NOTE:** The issue here *may* be related to a data structure issue.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48552238/152860) for the current state of play.

The following minimal example uses the `ggplot2` packages `economics` data and the NBER recession dates from the `tis` package.

Appreciate hints tips and incantations.

```
library(tis)
library(ggplot2)
# Prepare NBER recession start end dates.
start <- data.frame(date = as.Date(as.character(nberDates()[,"Start"]),"%Y%m%d"),
                    start= as.Date(as.character(nberDates()[,"Start"]),"%Y%m%d"))
end <- data.frame(date = as.Date(as.character(nberDates()[,"End"]),"%Y%m%d"),
                  end= as.Date(as.character(nberDates()[,"End"]),"%Y%m%d"))
dl <- economics %>% 
        gather(metric, value, pce:unemploy ) %>%
        group_by(metric) %>%
        mutate(diff = value - lag(value, default=first(value))) %>%
        mutate(pct = diff/value) %>%
        gather(transform, value, value:pct ) %>%
        full_join(x=., y=start, by=c('date' = 'date')) %>%
        full_join(x=., y=end, by=c('date' = 'date')) %>%
        mutate(ymin = 0) %>%
        mutate(ymax = Inf)
# Check the start end dates are present
dl %>% group_by(metric,transform, start) %>% summarise( count=n())

pl <- dl %>%
        do(
          plots = ggplot(data=., aes(x = date, y = value)) +
                      geom_point() +
                      geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)) +
                      stat_smooth(method="auto",size=1.5) +
                      facet_wrap(~transform, scales="free_y") 
          )  

pl[[1,2]]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried running your code. "start" & "end" values are predominantly NA... What values do you intend to plot for each facet's `geom_rect()`?

Comment: Correct.  There should be multiple regions shaded for each facet.  I don't want to plot and values, just shade top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue here is the construction of the data frame is non-trivial.  Two uses of outer join does not provide the required structure.

```
# Prepare NBER recession start end dates.
recessions <- data.frame(start = as.Date(as.character(nberDates()[,"Start"]),"%Y%m%d"),
                    end= as.Date(as.character(nberDates()[,"End"]),"%Y%m%d"))

# Create the long format data frame
dl <- economics %>% 
        gather(metric, value, pce:unemploy ) %>%
        group_by(metric) %>%
        mutate(diff = value - lag(value, default=first(value))) %>%
        mutate(pct = diff/value) %>%
        gather(transform, value, value:pct ) #%>%

# Build the data frame with start and end dates given in recessions 
df1 <- dl %>% 
        mutate(dummy=TRUE) %>% 
        left_join(recessions %>% mutate(dummy=TRUE)) %>% 
        filter(date >= start & date <= end) %>% 
        select(-dummy) 

# Build data frame of all other dates with start=NA and end=NA
df2 <- dl %>% 
        mutate(dummy=TRUE) %>% 
        left_join(recessions %>% mutate(dummy=TRUE)) %>% 
        mutate(start=NA, end=NA) %>%
        unique() %>%
        select(-dummy) 
# Now merge the two.  Overwirte NA values with start and end dates
dl <- df2 %>% 
      left_join(x=., y=df1, by="date") %>%
      mutate(date, start = ifelse(is.na(start.y), as.character(start.x), as.character(start.y)),end = ifelse(is.na(end.y), as.character(end.x), as.character(end.y))) %>%
      mutate(start=as.Date(start), end=as.Date(end) ) %>%
      select(-starts_with("start."),-starts_with("end."),-ends_with(".y")) %>% 
      setNames(sub(".x", "", names(.))) %>%
      mutate(ymin = -Inf) %>% #min(value)) %>%
      mutate(ymax = Inf) #max(value)) #%>%
# Check the start end dates are present
dl %>% group_by(metric,transform, start, end) %>% summarise( count = n() ) %>% print(n=180)

pl <- dl %>%
        group_by(metric) %>%
        do(
          plots = ggplot(data=., aes(x = date, y = value)) +
                      geom_point() +
                      # annotate('rect', xmin = start, xmax = end, 
                      #          ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, alpha = 0.5) +
                      geom_rect(aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), na.rm=TRUE) +
                      stat_smooth(method="auto",size=1.5) +
                      facet_wrap(~transform, scales="free_y") 
          )

grid.draw(pl[[1,2]])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that the minimum and maximum dates for each group are the same (NA group is not plotted):

```
dl %>% 
  group_by(transform) %>% 
  summarise(min= min(start, na.rm =TRUE), max = max(start, na.rm =TRUE))# 

A tibble: 4 x 3
  transform min        max       
  <chr>     <date>     <date>    
1 diff      1970-01-01 2008-01-01
2 pct       1970-01-01 2008-01-01
3 value     1970-01-01 2008-01-01
4 NA        1857-07-01 1960-05-01
```

Even if it is not the optimal solution, you can hard code both dates and  use `annotate` to avoid opacity as `geom_rect` will draw multiple rectangles. I added `alpha = 0.5` for transparency.

```
pl <- dl %>%
  do(
    plots = ggplot(data=., aes(x = date, y = value)) +
      geom_point() +
      annotate('rect', xmin = as.Date("1970-01-01"), xmax = as.Date("2008-01-01"), 
               ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, alpha = 0.5) +
      stat_smooth(method="auto",size=1.5) +
      facet_wrap(~transform, scales="free_y") 
  )  
pl[[1,2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Using `annotate` looks promising. But there are several shaded regions that need to be displayed, so I can't just take the first and last and hardcode them.

Comment: Hmm, I've just seen a wrinkle.  It appears the values `end` are all `NA`. For some reason the `full_join` is not working for the `end` data frame. Looking into this.